# SQL from Rows to Columns

Tags: sql-server

I am running a query over a server group containing, say, 5 instances...each of which have a database called TESTDB...and the server group is set to access only this database from each registered server within the server group.

I am running a query such as follows :

select serverproperty('servername'),file
from testdb_table

to get something like :

```
col 1       col2
instance-1 file1
instance-1 file2
instance-1 file3
instance-2 file1
instance-2 file2
instance-2 file3
instance-3 file1
instance-3 file3
```

which gives me the instance and the file in 2 separate columns.

Since the server group has 5 registered servers, I will see these registered servers in the first column whereas the file field will show in column 2.

I need to be able to pivot this data in a way so as to get something like :

```
INSTANCE-1     INSTANCE-2     INSTANCE-3
file1            file1          file1
file2            file2           
file3            file3          file3
```

etc.

The file field is a string field.

Since this query may be used on different server groups, I will not be able to know how many there are or what they are...so the query needs to be somewhat dynamic...

Thank you

Comment: Why the "No aggregates" restriction? Or you just don't see how they will be useful to you?

Comment: Because the values undearneath Field 2 will actually be strings...

Comment: `MAX`/`MIN` works fine on strings.